# Error de sintaxis en Laravel syntax error, unexpected ''/{any}'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy haciendo esto pero me lanza el siguiente error

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

    Route::get(uri:'/{any}', function(){
        return view(view:'spa');

    })->where(name:'any', expression:'.*');
```

syntax error, unexpected ''/{any}'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: Puede que ande un poco perdido, pero cuál es la razón de utilizar nomenclatura JSON?

Answer (score 0):

El primer parámetro que debes pasarle al método get es un string, el cuál indicaría la ruta, desconozco la sintaxis que intentas utilizar con `uri:'/{any}'`, yo simplemente pondría: `'/{any}'`

En el código de dicho método se puede apreciar:

```
/**
 * Register a new GET route with the router.
 *
 * @param  string  $uri
 * @param  \Closure|array|string|callable|null  $action
 * @return \Illuminate\Routing\Route
 */
public function get($uri, $action = null)
{
    return $this->addRoute(['GET', 'HEAD'], $uri, $action);
}
```

Al final para lo que se usa dicho string (`$uri`) es para asignar (reemplazando) la variable path en la clase Route, por lo cual no veo ningún tipo de valor estilo key/value que sea analizado o utilizado:

```
class Route implements \Serializable
{
    private $path = '/';

    // ...
```